# Derivative term in chain of LC coupled oscillators Hamiltonian

Tags: hamiltonian, coupled-oscillators

I am taking quantum superconducting circuits course and I cannot recover a formula provided by the lecturer.

I want to calculate the Hamiltonian of the following distributed element model of coplanar waveguide (without the coupling capacitor and resonator ends) starting from individual LC oscillator elements. [image: Coplanar waveguide as disctibited element]
The result is supposed to be $$H=\int_0^L \mathrm{d} x \frac{Q(x)^2}{2c} + \frac{1}{2l} \left(\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x}\right)^2$$ in the continuous limit.

My first intuition was that I should simply sum up energies stored in the capacitors and the inductors, but then the result is
$$H=\int_0^L \mathrm{d} x \frac{Q^2}{2c} + \frac{\Phi^2}{2l}$$
Also this is clearly wrong as the oscillators would be uncoupled. I need to find out what is $\Phi_{n+1}-\Phi_n$ (difference in flux in consecutive inductors) and then produce the derivative.

Then I derived the telegrapher's formula for the finite chain of LC oscillators and obtained
$$Q_{n+1}-Q_n=C\frac{d \Phi_n}{dt},$$ $$\Phi_{n+1}-\Phi_n=L\frac{d Q_{n+1}}{d t}$$
Where $Q_n$ ($\Phi_n$) are charge (flux) on nth capacitor (inductor).
The second equation looks like something I am looking for (to generate the difference and then make a derivative) but since it involves a time derivative on the RHS, I have no idea how I should incorporate this into the Hamiltonian?

Comment: Your inductors link neighboring sites, so the flux through them is related to the difference in voltage from site to site. You can surely get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

For your Hamiltonian to be useful, you need to specify which variables are conjugate (or more generally a Poisson bracket). Without this knowledge, you cannot derive the equations of motion. When you have no clue, it’s best to revert to the Lagrangian and do the usual Legendre transform.

Let’s look at the discrete case to build up intuition. Using your conventions, you have the equation of motion (Kirchoff’s current law at node $n$):
$$
L\ddot Q_n+\frac{1}{C}(2Q_n-Q_{n+1}-Q_{n-1})=0
$$
Or equivalently:
$$
C\ddot \Phi_n+\frac{1}{L}(2\Phi_n-\Phi_{n+1}-\Phi_{n-1})=0
$$
so you get the respective Lagrangians:
$$
\mathcal L_Q=\sum \frac{L}{2}\dot Q_n^2-\frac{1}{2C}(Q_{n+1}-Q_n)^2 \\
\mathcal L_\Phi=\sum \frac{C}{2}\dot \Phi_n^2-\frac{1}{2L}(\Phi_n-\Phi_{n-1})^2
$$
You get the respective conjugate variables:
$$
(Q_n,\hat Q_n)\quad\hat Q_n= L\dot Q_n = \Phi_n-\Phi_{n-1} \\
(\hat\Phi_n,\Phi_n)\quad\hat \Phi_n= C\dot \Phi_n = Q_{n+1}-Q_n \\
$$
and in either case, you end up with the same Hamiltonian:
$$
\mathcal H = \sum \frac{1}{2L}\hat Q_n^2+\frac{1}{2C}(Q_{n+1}-Q_n)^2 \\
=\sum \frac{1}{2C}\hat \Phi_n^2+\frac{1}{2L}(\Phi_n-\Phi_{n-1})^2\\
= \sum \frac{1}{2C}(Q_{n+1}-Q_n)^2+\frac{1}{2L}(\Phi_n-\Phi_{n-1})^2
$$
Note that $Q_n,\Phi_n$ are not canonically conjugate. If you want to recover your telegrapher’s equations from the third expression of the Hamiltonian, you’ll need to use the non-canonical Poisson bracket between the two variables (it will depend on the boundary conditions).

From this, you easily recover the continuum limit:
$$
H=\int dx \left[\frac{1}{2c}(\partial_xQ)^2+\frac{1}{2l}(\partial_x\Phi)^2\right]
$$
This means that both the supposed result and your intuition are wrong which can also be seen directly using dimensional analysis. Note that the same caveat for canonical conjugate variables still applies.

**Method 2**

There is a way for you to interpret your quantity as a Hamiltonian. Things are simpler in the continuum limit (normalized capacitance/inductance per unit length up to a change of units):
\begin{align}
\partial_t\Phi&=\partial_x Q &
\partial_tQ&=\partial_x \Phi
\end{align}

Like in EM, you can introduce a potential $\lambda$ such that:
\begin{align}
Q&=\partial_x\lambda &
\Phi&=\partial_t\lambda
\end{align}

From this, the second equation is automatically satisfied and the first one becomes:
$$
\partial_t^2\lambda =\partial_x^2\lambda
$$
Which can be obtained by the Lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal L=\int dt dx\frac{1}{2}(\partial_t\lambda^2-\partial_x\lambda^2)
$$
Back to the original fields, this gives the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian:
$$
\mathcal L=\int dt dx\frac{1}{2}(\Phi^2-Q^2)\\
\mathcal H=\int dx\frac{1}{2}(\Phi^2+Q^2)
$$
Which is precisely the Hamiltonian you were looking for.

The discrete analogue would be:

\begin{align}
\dot\Phi_n&=Q_{n+1}-Q_n &\dot Q_n&=\Phi_n-\Phi_{n-1}
\end{align}
so:
\begin{align}
Q_n&=\lambda_n-\lambda_{n-1} &
\Phi_n&=\dot\lambda_n
\end{align}
$$
\ddot\lambda_n=\lambda_{n+1}+\lambda_{n-1}-2\lambda_n
$$
which gives the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal L&=\int dt \sum\frac{1}{2}(\dot\lambda_n^2-(\lambda_n-\lambda_{n-1})^2)\\
&=\int dt \frac{1}{2}\sum\Phi_n^2-Q_n^2\\
\mathcal H&= \frac{1}{2}\sum \Phi_n^2+Q_n^2
\end{align}
$$

This time, the Poisson bracket is given by:
$$
\{Q_m,\Phi_n\}=\delta_{mn}-\delta_{m-1,n}
$$
and in the continuum limit:
$$
\{Q(x),\Phi(y)\}=\delta'(x-y)
$$
which is different from the previous method.

Note that in either case, the Hamiltonian is conserved up to boundary terms, so the exact conservation depends on the boundary conditions.

Hope this helps.